# Why do the counterterms of different Green's functions not interfere with each other and destroy renormalisation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, greens-functions, correlation-functions

Say I want to renormalize the 3 point 1PI Green's function of some theory in some order. How can I be sure that this also gets rid of the respective divergencies in say the self energy?

An example: Consider a real massless scalar field theory with cubic and quartic interaction,
\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} ( \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - m^2 \phi^2) - \bar{\mu}^\epsilon \frac{\lambda_3}{3!} \phi^3 - \bar{\mu}^{2\epsilon} \frac{\lambda_4}{4!} \phi^4 .
\end{equation}
We start renormalizing the 3-point function up to order $\mathcal{O} (\lambda_3 \lambda_4)$ with the diagram
[image]
The principal part of this diagram is just $1/\epsilon$. Thus we introduce the counterterm (I am using the $\overline{MS}$-scheme here)
\begin{equation} 
\delta_1 \mathcal{L} = \frac{\lambda_4}{16 \pi^2}  \left( \frac{3}{2 \epsilon} \right) (-\bar{\mu}^\epsilon \frac{\lambda_3}{3!} \phi^4 ) 
\end{equation}
The factor $3/2$ has been included to account for 3 equivalent diagrams and a symmetry factor of $1/2$.
If we now want to compute the self-energy up to order $\mathcal{O}(\lambda_3^2 \lambda_4)$  then the relevant divergence must cancel with this counter term once we take into account all diagrams. And it turns out that it cancel indeed.

I understand that it has to cancel in order to have a renormalizable theory but I see no underlying reason why it always must (I get the why but not the how).